# Questions about NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsuserdefaults

I have a couple of questions about NSUserDefaults in Mac OS X:

1. When does the NSUserDefaults use the dictionary provided by registerDefaults? Only the first time the application is opened or every time the application is opened?
2. Where is the information from NSUserDefaults stored?
3. How can I reset NSUSerDefaults?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Only the first time. But you can force an application to reuse the defaults with the terminal.
2. ~/Library/Preferences/YourIdentifier.plist (e.g. com.apple.finder.plist)
3. Terminal: defaults delete YourIdentifier (e.g. com.apple.finder)
   Code: `[NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults];`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I have one more question and I don't want to create a new question. If my NSSlider is binded to a value, and I change that value programatically, will my NSSlider change its old value to new value automatically? (Since it's binded). I tried, but tis doesn't work, but it should right? What's the point of binding if it doesn't.. Thanks!

Comment: For 1.: The `registerDefaults:` dictionary is used every time for any key that doesn't exist in the saved user defaults, actually. Those defaults aren't written out unless they change.

Comment: @user635064: You *should* create a new question for that. It has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: I have found that even deleting that file, and launching the app won't reset the settings. The settings seem to remain somewhere else, in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it should change. I would try it with other controls like NSTextField. When it doesn't work you're doing it wrong

The idea of binding is exactly what you thought it is.